# Android layout overlap buttons on bottom of each other

Tags: android, xml

I want to overlap buttons on bottom of layout, like this: 
[image: overlap buttons on bottom of layout]

How to do it in android studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it by minus padding on parent `RelativeLayout` like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/loading1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-34dp"
    android:background="@drawable/alert">
```